# upgrade existing recovery partition to windows 8.1

Tags: windows, windows-8, lenovo-laptop, windows-8.1-upgrade

I am using Lenovo G510 Notebook. It came with windows 8.0 recovery option and Lenovo One key recovery (OKR). I have upgraded my windows to 8.1 from windows Store.

Now I want to update my recovery partition to save windows 8.1 so anytime I want to reset my PC again it should defaults to windows 8.1 not on 8.0.  I checked the recovery options in control panel but it wants me to use USB drive I want USB less recovery to windows 8.1.

Please guide me how do I update my existing recovery partition.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done because the original recovery partition contains a WIM of the factory image from Lenovo and any other specific tools that allow the recovery to be completed successfully. The WIM won't be easily editable as it may be split into different parts and/or the scripts used to automate the recovery procedure may check the WIM integrity using a size of hash of the file(s) to ensure the WIM is intact.

**In a nutshell: It's not worth attempting and could break your recovery leaving you with the possibility of having to buy recovery DVDs/USB from Lenovo if you don't have your own.**